# Use function to write to .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've never particularly used JS much, with the exception of basic animations,

The page I'm working on requires me to fade out the active div and fade the requested one in, I have around 25 different div's I'll be fading between. At the minute I can't think of how to only fade the active one out so I'm trying to fade every div but the one that's requested out.

Here's the code I'm attempting to get working

```
    var active = 0;

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
if (i != active){

document.write("$('."+array[i]+"').fadeOut(900);");
}
```

naturally i know the document.write shouldn't be there, but ideally that code has to be printed into the .js file I'm using, however. I don't have a clue how to print it to the .js.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, or a way to do this in php without a page reload!

Comment: replace `document.write("$('."+array[i]+"').fadeOut(900);");` with `$('."+array[i]+"').fadeOut(900);`

Comment: if you define "active div" I expect some hints will be forthcoming

Comment: What ".js" are you printing to? Your `document.write` attempt looks totally hinky.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Or a variant that actually works, like `$('.' + array[i]).fadeOut(900);`

Comment: What does "array" contain exactly? A list of divs? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @Alnitak the active div is basically the main content div of the page with several child divs that features one product range, each array value is the parent div name of another range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find yourself generating code on the fly, it usually indicates that you want to take a step back and re-evaluate your approach. :-)

In this case, there's no need to create the JavaScript dynamically. It's just a matter of running the code.

I wasn't sure what your definition of "active" was, so here's something that fades divs in/out on the basis of what buttons you press:

The HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='1'>
<input type='button' value='2'>
<input type='button' value='3'>
<input type='button' value='4'>
<input type='button' value='5'>
<input type='button' value='6'>
<div id='container'>
  <div class='c1'>This is c1</div>
  <div class='c2'>This is c2</div>
  <div class='c3'>This is c3</div>
  <div class='c4'>This is c4</div>
  <div class='c5'>This is c5</div>
  <div class='c6'>This is c6</div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript (teaching version):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Hook our buttons; this selector hooks all of them,
  // so you probably want to narrow that down, but I
  // have no idea what your definition of "active" is,
  // so I made one up.
  $(":button").click(function() {

    // Get the value of the button, e.g., 1, 2
    var val = this.value; 

    // Get all of the divs in the container
    var divs = $("#container div");

    // Fade out all of the ones that aren't our target;
    // fade in the one that is
    divs.not(".c" + val).fadeOut(900);
    divs.filter(".c" + val).fadeIn(900);
  });

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ucufe3/)

That does this:

1. Uses the jQuery [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function (the shortcut form where I just pass a function into the `jQuery` function) to run the code when the page is "ready" (the DOM has been built)
2. Looks up all divs we want to be dealing with. In my case, it's all the divs in a container, but you can use just about [any CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) you want ([and then some](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).
3. Uses [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with a class selector to filter out the div that has the target class, then uses `fadeOut` to start fading the other ones out.
4. Uses [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set to just our target div, and `fadeIn` to start fading it in.

That version is for clarity. Here's a more concise version (still perfectly clear to people who know jQuery well, but tricky for folks still finding their feet):

The JavaScript (chained version using [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Hook our buttons; this selector hooks all of them,
  // so you probably want to narrow that down, but I
  // have no idea what your definition of "active" is,
  // so I made one up.
  $(":button").click(function() {

    // Get the value of the button, e.g., 1, 2
    var val = this.value; 

    // Get all of the divs in the container
    // Fade out all of the ones that aren't our target;
    // fade in the one that is
    $("#container div")
      .not(".c" + val).fadeOut(900)
      .end()
      .filter(".c" + val).fadeIn(900);
  });

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ucufe3/2)

Comment: thanks for this one, it's a great basis to go off with what i'm aiming for!

Comment: @user: No worries, I figured an example would help. Best,

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are using document.write instead of simply executing the javascript.

```
var active = 0;

for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
if (i != active) {
    $("."+array[i]).fadeOut(900);
}
```

Additionally, try using a jQuery selector to select all the non-active divs by adding an additional class to each div:

```
var active = array[0];
var classname = "some_class";

$("div." + classname + ":not(." + active + ")").fadeOut(900);
```

You could even just select the visible divs that are not the active one and fade them out:

```
var active = array[0];
var classname = "some_class";

$("div." + classname + ":not(." + active + "):visible").fadeOut(900);
```

Comment: although it's better IMHO to use the `.not()` function rather than construct a selector string with `:not()` in it.